# Сравнение двух запросов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница двух запросов

[image: на картинке схема]

```
SELECT * FROM Courts
WHERE Id = ANY (SELECT CourtId FROM Matches)


SELECT * FROM Courts
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CourtId FROM Matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут всё просто

```
SELECT * FROM Courts
WHERE Id = ANY (SELECT CourtId FROM Matches)
```

дай все Courts которые совпадают с Matches

```
SELECT * FROM Courts
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CourtId FROM Matches)
```

дай все Courts если существует хотя бы одна в Matches

так как результат первой не нулевой отсюда следует что

```
EXISTS (SELECT CourtId FROM Matches)
```

всегда true